# What's a fast way to sketch $y=\sin (5x) + \frac{3}{10}x \sin (5x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

What's a fast way to sketch $y= \sin (5x) + \frac{3}{10}x \sin (5x)$ ?

I had this question as part of a recent test paper and I had to sketch it for the range $0 \leq x \leq \pi$ . It was for only 2 marks so there must be a faster way to sketch it than my method of serial substitution of x values.

Comment: I think one helpful thing would be to factor:  $\sin(5x)(1+\frac 3{10}x)$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by factoring the function:

$$y=\left(1+\frac 3{10}x\right)\sin(5x)$$

Putting this form together with the limits, you have a sine wave whose amplitude is linearly increasing from $1$ to $1+{3\pi\over 10}\approx 2$ and whose period is $5$ times shorter than $\sin x$.  The limits are $0$ to $\pi$ and so there would be $\dfrac 52$ cycles of $2\pi$ portions of sine wave in your graph, or three waves above $0$ and two waves below, with the amplitude linearly increasing in both directions.  The start and end points would both be on $y=0$, and there would be four other zeroes in between that are equally spaced across $[0,\pi]$ at $\frac \pi 5, \frac {2\pi}5,\frac {3\pi}5,\frac {4\pi}5.$

Comment: Thank you but can you explain how you arrive at these conclusions? For example, how do you know that the amplitude is linearly increasing from $1$ to $1+{3\pi\over 10}$?

Comment: The form of the factored equation is $y=a\sin bx$, which is where $a$ is the amplitude, and $b$ is the inverse-period.  Since the $a$ term is also a function (namely $1+\frac 3{10}x$), it is necessary to analyze what type of function it is, and it turns out to be linear (in $x$).

Comment: Oh I get it now, $a$ is a linear function